# How to replace multiple column values on a condition when-then-otherwise in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df_ = pl.DataFrame({'r_num':['Yes','','Yes'],'pin':['Yes','',''],'fin':['','','']})
```

[image]

Here I would like to find an observation which has r_num is YES, pin is Yes and fin is EMPTY. on meeting this condition r_num and pin should be filled in as EMPTY.

```
df_.with_columns(pl.when((pl.col('r_num')=='Yes') &  (pl.col('pin')=='Yes') & (pl.col('fin') !='Yes')
                        ).then(pl.col('r_num')=='').otherwise(pl.col('r_num')))
```

[image]

Here why r_num is getting filled up with false?

Here is a syantax that i'm following. how to specify  multiple columns in **then** clause.

expected output will be:

[image]

Here is a syntax to implement the same in pandas:

```
df_.loc[(df_['r_num']=='Yes') & (df_['pin']=='Yes') & (df_['fin']!='Yes'),['r_num','pin']]=''
``
```

Comment: For documentation, this response shows how to accomplish changing multiple columns within a single `when/then/otherwise`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73718390/18559875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a small bug in your code. Within the `.then()` method, you'd specified

```py
pl.col('r_num')==''
```

This evaluates to `False` for the first row (where the `when` condition is `True`). The behaviour of `.then()` is to insert that value into the cell that is being evaluated.

What you want is `.then("")`, and to tell polars that you want to essentially overwrite `r_num` (and `pin`) with `.alias("r_num")` / `.alias("pin")`.

Since the value in `.otherwise` depends on which column you want to overwrite, I think we have to perform the loop twice:

```py
(
    df_
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.when((pl.col("r_num") == "Yes") & (pl.col("pin") == "Yes") & (pl.col("fin") != "Yes"))
            .then("") # changed here
            .otherwise(pl.col("r_num"))
            .alias("r_num"), # added this
            pl.when((pl.col("r_num") == "Yes") & (pl.col("pin") == "Yes") & (pl.col("fin") != "Yes"))
            .then("") # changed here
            .otherwise(pl.col("pin"))
            .alias("pin"), # added this
            ]
        )
)
```

This results in your desired output:

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────┬─────┐
│ r_num ┆ pin ┆ fin │
│ ---   ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str   ┆ str ┆ str │
╞═══════╪═════╪═════╡
│       ┆     ┆     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│       ┆     ┆     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Yes   ┆     ┆     │
└───────┴─────┴─────┘
```