# How to swap column values on conditions in python polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a data frame as below:

```
df_n = pl.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'last_name':[np.nan,'mallesh','bhavik'],
                                    'first_name':['a','b','c'],
                                    'middle_name_or_initial':['aa','bb','cc']}))
```

[image]

Here I would like to find an observation which has First and Middle Name not NULL and Last Name is Null, in this case first_name should be swapped to last_name and middle_name should be swapped to first_name, and middle_name to be EMPTY.

expected output will be:

[image]

I'm trying with this command:

```
df_n.with_columns([
    pl.when((pl.col('first_name').is_not_null()) & (pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').is_not_null()) & (pl.col('last_name').is_null())
           ).then(pl.col('first_name').alias('last_name')).otherwise(pl.col('last_name').alias('first_name')),
    pl.when((pl.col('first_name').is_not_null()) & (pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').is_not_null()) & (pl.col('last_name').is_null())
           ).then(pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').alias('first_name')).otherwise('').alias('middle_name_or_initial')
]
)
```

[image]

Here it is throwing a wrong output and any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually change the values of multiple columns within a single `when/then/otherwise` statement.

##### The Algorithm

```py
name_cols = ["last_name", "first_name", "middle_name_or_initial"]
(
    df_n.with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col("first_name").is_not_null())
            & (pl.col("middle_name_or_initial").is_not_null())
            & (pl.col("last_name").is_null())
        )
        .then(pl.struct([
            pl.col('first_name').alias('last_name'),
            pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').alias('first_name'),
            pl.col('last_name').alias('middle_name_or_initial'),
        ]))
        .otherwise(pl.struct(name_cols))
        .alias('name_struct')
    )
    .drop(name_cols)
    .unnest('name_struct')
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ middle_name_or_initial │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---                    │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str                    │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ a         ┆ aa         ┆ null                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mallesh   ┆ b          ┆ bb                     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bhavik    ┆ c          ┆ cc                     │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

##### How it works

To change the values of multiple columns within a single `when/then/otherwise` statement, we can use structs.  But you must observe some rules with structs.  In all your `then` and `otherwise` statements, your structs must have:

- the same field names
- in the same order
- with the same data type in corresponding fields.

So, in both the `then` and `otherwise` statements, I'm going to create a struct with field names in this order:

1. last_name: string
2. first_name: string
3. middle_name_or_initial: string

In our `then` statement, I'm swapping values and using `alias` to ensure that my fields names are as stated above.  (This is important.)

```py
.then(pl.struct([
            pl.col('first_name').alias('last_name'),
            pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').alias('first_name'),
            pl.col('last_name').alias('middle_name_or_initial'),
        ]))
```

And in the `otherwise` statement, we'll simply name the existing columns that we want, in the order that we want - using the list `name_cols` that I created in a previous step.

```py
name_cols = ["last_name", "first_name", "middle_name_or_initial"]
...
.otherwise(pl.struct(name_cols))
```

Here's the result after the `when/then/otherwise` statement.

```py
name_cols = ["last_name", "first_name", "middle_name_or_initial"]
(
    df_n.with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col("first_name").is_not_null())
            & (pl.col("middle_name_or_initial").is_not_null())
            & (pl.col("last_name").is_null())
        )
        .then(pl.struct([
            pl.col('first_name').alias('last_name'),
            pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').alias('first_name'),
            pl.col('last_name').alias('middle_name_or_initial'),
        ]))
        .otherwise(pl.struct(name_cols))
        .alias('name_struct')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ middle_name_or_initial ┆ name_struct          │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---                    ┆ ---                  │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str                    ┆ struct[3]            │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ null      ┆ a          ┆ aa                     ┆ {"a","aa",null}      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mallesh   ┆ b          ┆ bb                     ┆ {"mallesh","b","bb"} │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bhavik    ┆ c          ┆ cc                     ┆ {"bhavik","c","cc"}  │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Notice that our new struct `name_struct` has the values that we want - in the correct order.

Next, we will use [`unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) to break the struct into separate columns.  (But first, we must drop the existing columns so that we don't get 2 sets of columns with the same names.)

```py
name_cols = ["last_name", "first_name", "middle_name_or_initial"]
(
    df_n.with_column(
        pl.when(
            (pl.col("first_name").is_not_null())
            & (pl.col("middle_name_or_initial").is_not_null())
            & (pl.col("last_name").is_null())
        )
        .then(pl.struct([
            pl.col('first_name').alias('last_name'),
            pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').alias('first_name'),
            pl.col('last_name').alias('middle_name_or_initial'),
        ]))
        .otherwise(pl.struct(name_cols))
        .alias('name_struct')
    )
    .drop(name_cols)
    .unnest('name_struct')
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ middle_name_or_initial │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---                    │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str                    │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ a         ┆ aa         ┆ null                   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mallesh   ┆ b          ┆ bb                     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bhavik    ┆ c          ┆ cc                     │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

With `pl.when().then().otherwise()` you create values for only one column (so only one alias at the end is allowed).

```py
In [67]: df_n.with_columns(
    ...:     [
    ...:         # Create temp column with filter, so it does not have to be recalculated 3 times.
    ...:         ((pl.col('first_name').is_not_null()) & (pl.col('middle_name_or_initial').is_not_null()) & (pl.col('last_name').is_null())).alias("swap_names")
    ...:     ]
    ...: ).with_columns(
    ...:     [
    ...:         # Create new columns with the correct value based on the swap_names column.
    ...:         pl.when(pl.col("swap_names")).then(pl.col("first_name")).otherwise(pl.col("last_name")).alias("last_name_new"),
    ...:         pl.when(pl.col("swap_names")).then(pl.col("middle_name_or_initial")).otherwise(pl.col("first_name")).alias("first_name_new"),
    ...:         pl.when(pl.col("swap_names")).then(None).otherwise(pl.col("middle_name_or_initial")).alias("middle_name_or_initial_new"),
    ...:     ]
    ...: )
Out[67]: 
shape: (3, 7)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ last_name ┆ first_name ┆ middle_name_or_initial ┆ swap_names ┆ last_name_new ┆ first_name_new ┆ middle_name_or_initial_new │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---                    ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---            ┆ ---                        │
│ str       ┆ str        ┆ str                    ┆ bool       ┆ str           ┆ str            ┆ str                        │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════════════════╡
│ null      ┆ a          ┆ aa                     ┆ true       ┆ a             ┆ aa             ┆ null                       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ mallesh   ┆ b          ┆ bb                     ┆ false      ┆ mallesh       ┆ b              ┆ bb                         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ bhavik    ┆ c          ┆ cc                     ┆ false      ┆ bhavik        ┆ c              ┆ cc                         │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
```